# how can I create this DynamoDb table group with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We can create, edit, delete group from AWS Console to maintain a logical grouping of DynamoDb tables. I searched over AWS documentation and forums but did not find a way on how can I create this DynamoDb table group with CloudFormation or how can I create a table inside a group with AWS .NET SDK.
Is this even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table groups exist only on the AWS console UI. There is no such resource on AWS that is why they aren't available neither on CloudFormation nor on CDK.

Comment: It is possible to create a resource group that will automatically get picked up by the DDB console by using the tag key: `DDBTableGroupKey-{yourgroupname}`

Comment: @RandallHunt that's new to me. I'll update my reply shortly. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I don't know if it was supported at the time you wrote the original answer. Luckily it works now!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the the [resource groups API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/gettingstarted-query.html#gettingstarted-query-cli-tag) to create a resource group defined by a tag prefixed with `DDBTableGroupKey-` that the DynamoDB console will automatically pull it in.

E.g.

```py
import json
import boto3

rg = boto3.client('resource-groups')
resource_query = json.dumps({
    "ResourceTypeFilters": ["AWS::DynamoDB::Table"], 
    "TagFilters": [
        {"Key": "DDBTableGroupKey-PROD", "Values": ["PROD"]}
    ]
})
rg.create_group(
    Name='PROD',
    ResourceQuery={'Type': 'TAG_FILTERS_1_0', 'Query': resource_query}
)
```

Then tag the relevant tables with `DDBTableGroupKey-PROD`, `PROD`.

Then they should appear in the console as a group.

In CDK you could create this by using:

```js
const group = "lolprod"
cdk.Tag.add(this, `DDBTableGroupKey-${group}`, group)
```

and

```js
new resourcegroups.CfnGroup(this, id, {
    name: group,
    resourceQuery: {query: '...', type: '...'}
})
```